# Find the lowest height and lowest width among all images in a directory

Tags: command-line, scripts, imagemagick, image-processing

How can I get the lowest height out of all heights and also the lowest width out of all widths given I have about 50k images?

I tried this command, but it only gives the width and height of an image:

```
identify -format '%w %h' 72028059_11.jpg
600 431
```

I also got this from IRC Linux channel, but, because I have 50k images, it takes forever to output any result:

```
find -type f -name \*.jpg -exec identify -format '%w %h %d/%f\n' {} \; | sort -n -k2
```

Comment: Running `-exec ... {} \;` with 50k files is insane. Just using `{} +` should speed things up.

Answer (score 5):

#### Getting the image with min height and width

I don't have any comparing statistics, but I have reasons to believe the script below offers a relatively good option, since:

- python's PIL [does not load the image into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034942/1391444) when calling `.open`
- The script itself does not store the list of all files, it simply looks per file if the next one has a smaller height or width.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PIL import Image
import os
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]
# set an initial value which no image will meet
minw = 10000000
minh = 10000000

for image in os.listdir(path):
    # get the image height & width
    image_location = os.path.join(path, image)
    im = Image.open(image_location)
    data = im.size
    # if the width is lower than the last image, we have a new "winner"
    w = data[0]
    if w < minw:
        newminw = w, image_location
        minw = w
    # if the height is lower than the last image, we have a new "winner"
    h = data[1]
    if h < minh:
        newminh = h, image_location
        minh = h
# finally, print the values and corresponding files
print("minwidth", newminw)
print("minheight", newminh)
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `get_minsize.py`
2. Run it with the directory of images as argument:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/get_maxsize.py /path/to/imagefolder
   ```

Output like:

```
minwidth (520, '/home/jacob/Desktop/caravan/IMG_20171007_104917.jpg')
minheight (674, '/home/jacob/Desktop/caravan/butsen1.jpg')
```

#### NB

The script assumes the image folder is a "flat" directory with (only) images. If that is not the case, a few lines need to be added, just mention.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$ find -type f -name \*.jpg -exec identify -format '%w %h %d/%f\n' {} + | sort -n -k1 > sorted_width
$ sort -k 1rn sorted_width
$ find -type f -name \*.jpg -exec identify -format '%w %h %d/%f\n' {} + | sort -n -k2 > sorted_height
$ sort -k 2rn sorted_height
```

Comment: Rather than just specifying commands, perhaps you can explain how each actually does what the user wants it to do?

Answer (score 0):

From: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155627/343966

You can use the ImageMagic package with the following command:

```
identify -format "%w %h %f\n" *.png | sort -n -r -k 1 | head -n 3
```

`-k 1` sorts on the widths, change to `-k 2` to sort on the heights. `-r` reverse the sorting, outputting the highest width or height, remove it to get the lowest ones.